# Remove checkmark from „Include Attachments With Replies“ in Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, email

I'm using a Mac with macOS Monterey 12.6.6 (21G646) and Apple Mail 16.0 (3696.120.41.1.3).

In Apple's Mail app under the Menu bar>Edit there's a setting `Include Attachments With Replies`

By default there's no checkmark, like here:

[image: no checkmark]

But unfortunately, I clicked one of them by mistake. Now it looks like this:

[image: with checkmark]

I can switch between the 4 options but I'm not able to remove the checkmark, as it was before I accidentally checked one of them.

But I want to remove the checkmark because with checkmark the behavior isn't as I want it. None of the options does the same as `no checkmark`. The missing option would be `Always, but only when forwarding (not when replying)`. This is what happens, when none of them would be selected.

Does anyone have an idea how I can remove the checkmark? Is there a simple way? Or maybe I can edit some preferences file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the solution myself.

**You have to do the following:**

1. Quit the Mail app
2. Go to
   `~/Library/Containers/Mail/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist`
3. Open `com.apple.mail.plist` file, e.g. in Xcode
4. Remove the parameter `MFAttachmentBehaviorKey`
5. Safe the file and start Mail
6. Done!

**HINT:**

You may need to change `Mail` to `com.apple.mail` in the path. Background is the following: You may see multiple folders called `Mail` in `~/Library/Containers/`. You may think, these are all duplicates, but they aren't. `Mail` isn't their real name. You can check the real name for each of them by opening the information window with `⌘+i`. Under the section `Name & Extension` you will see the real name, like `com.apple.mail`, `com.apple.mail.MailQuickLookExtension` or `com.apple.MailShareExtension`.

**EDIT**: If you're using macOS Ventura check comment of Aussie Geek.

Comment: For Ventura, this does not work exactly as described. Rather in Step 4, do not remove the `MFAttachmentBehaviorKey`. Instead, edit its value to 0. (Note: I had to make a copy of the `com.apple.mail.plist` file on my desktop, change it there, and then replace the one in the `~/Library/Containers/Mail/Data/Library/Preferences` folder with the edited one.)

Comment: @AussieGeek You're right, thanks. If anyone else reads this: The row must be as follows: `Key= MFAttachmentBehaviorKey; Type=Number; Value=0`